# Passing runtime parameters throughout application

Tags: c#, oop

I have a legacy C# library (a set of interrelated algorithms) in which there is a global god object which is passed to all classes. This god object (simply called Manager :D ) has a Parameters member, and an ObjectCollection member (among lots of others).

```
public class Manager
{
    public Parameters {get; private set;}
    public ObjectCollection {get; private set;}
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am unable to test the algorithms because everything takes the manager as dependency, and initializing that means I have to initialize everything. So I want to refactor this design.

Parameters has more than 100 fields in it, the values control the different algorithms. The ObjectCollection has the entities required for the overall execution of the engine, stored by Id, by Name, etc.

The following are the approaches I've though of, but not satisfied with:

1. Pass Parameters and ObjectCollection (or IParameters and IObjectCollection) instead of the Manager, but I don't think this solves any issue. I wouldn't know which of the parameters the algorithms would depend on.
2. Splitting the parameters class to smaller ones also is difficult as one parameter may affect many algorithms, so a logical separation is difficult. Plus the dependencies for each algorithm may end up to be many.
3. A singleton pattern like is usually done for a Logger, but that too is not testable.
4. Some of the parameters control the algorithm logic, some of the parameters are just required for the algorithm. I'm thinking of making each algorithm a separate class implementing an interface, and at the application start, deciding which algorithm to instantiate based on the parameter. I might end up splitting the current set of algorithm classes to many more, and I'm afraid I'll end up complicating it more and losing the structure of the algorithms.

Is there any standard way to deal with this, or is just splitting big classes to smaller ones and passing dependencies by constructor the only general advice?

Comment: Have you tried making the manager a public static variable? It can then be read by all classes, and also edited by them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to allow yourself to make small steps I'd start with a single algorithm and identify the parameters it requires. These can then be exposed in an interface so...

```
public interface IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm1 
{
  int OneThing {get;}
  int AnotherThing {get;}
}
```

Then you can alter `Manager` so that it implements that interface and as in @marcel's answer expose those parameters directly on Manager.

Now you can test Algorithm1 with a very small mock or self-shunt because you don't need to initialise a gigantic Manager in order to run your test. And Algorithm1 no longer knows it takes a Manager object.

```
public Manager : IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm1 {}

public class Algorithm1 
{
  public Algorithm1(IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm1 parameters){}
}
```

Bit by bit you can continue expanding this to each of the sets of parameters and dealing with small, specific interfaces will allow you to identify where different algorithms have common parameters.

```
public Manager : 
  IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm1, 
  IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm2, 
  IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm3, 
  IAmTheParametersForAlgorithm4 {}
```

It also means that as you identify algorithms whose parameters are no longer accessed outside of their interface you can stop injecting Manager into those algorithms, take the parameters out of Manager, and create a new class which only provides those parameters.

This means you can keep your application running the whole time you're making this change if you aren't able to dedicate time to make one gigantic breaking change

Comment: I have been trying this method, and it works really well! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For the Parameters, I would go with something like this:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}

public class AlgorithmParameters1
{
    private Parameters parameters;

    public int MyProperty1 { get { return parameters.MyProperty1; } }

    public int MyProperty3 { get { return parameters.MyProperty3; } }

    public AlgorithmParameters1(Parameters parameters)
    {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

public class Algorithm1
{
    public void Run(AlgorithmParameters1 parameters)
    {
        //Access only MyProperty1 and MyProperty3...
    }
}
```

Usage would look like:

```
var parameters = new Parameters()
{
    MyProperty1 = 4,
    MyProperty2 = 5,
    MyProperty3 = 6,
};

new Algorithm1().Run(new AlgorithmParameters1(parameters));
```

By the way, I don't see how you could differ between parameters that control an algorithm and are required for it. By control do you mean they are used to make a decision which algorithm to take?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The parameters control the internal working of the algorithm. For example, a parameter called UseFractionalCounts would determine if a division operation should result in an int or double.